# speed up one step ahead predictions (instead of using rollapply)

Tags: r, time-series

i use `rollapply`in order to create 1-step ahead forecasts of a GARCH(1,1) model (`garchFit`). An example is provided below:

```
require(fGarch)
require(zoo)
data(EuStockMarkets)  
dax <- diff(log(EuStockMarkets))[,"DAX"]


gfit <- function(df)
   { 
  series <- df
    capture.output(gf <- garchFit(formula=~arma(0,0) + garch(1,1), data=series),     file='NUL')
    g <- predict(gf, n.ahead=1)[,2]
    attributes(g) <- NULL
return(g)
   }

 rolling <- rollapply(dax, width=250, FUN=gfit)
```

However, this takes a relatively long time. So my question is: Is there a method of speeding this up?

Comment: thanks a lot! it cut the whole thing by roughly a half. before: `user  system elapsed 206.36    2.46  226.04`; after: `user  system elapsed  122.30    0.31  123.04`. so this helps a lot. but probably there are further possibilities :)

Comment: now i have lot's of [output](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19Fdy_iD-gfJYailOM_qGXOi3g5iXpCrQIqsYkzkqWpc) am i seeing this right that converting the whole thing into a `ts`object takes a huge fraction? is there a resource on interpreting the `Rprof` output. Thanks a **lot**!

Comment: Since it seems that we have converged on an answer I have deleted my comments and transferred them to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There was a bug in recent versions of `rollapply` (such as zoo 1.7-6) that did not result in incorrect answers but did cause it to run much more slowly than need be. Try the development version (to become zoo 1.7-7) and see if that is sufficient for your needs:

   install.packages("zoo", repo = "http://r-forge.r-project.org")
2. You can also try measuring the percentage of time taken up by your function (see `?Rprof`) and if its large, i.e. `total.pct` for `FUN` is large, then its pointless to look for `rollapply` alternatives.