# Subset xts object by time of day

Tags: r, time, time-series, xts

A simple question: I know how to subset time series in `xts` for years, months and days from the help: `x['2000-05/2001']` and so on.

But how can I subset my data by hours of the day? I would like to get all data between 07:00 am and 06:00 pm. I.e., I want to extract the data during business time - irrelevant of the day (I take care for weekends later on). Help has an example of the form:

```
.parseISO8601('T08:30/T15:00')
```

But this does not work in my case. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example?

Comment: If your `xts` object is called `x` then something like `y <- x["T09:30/T11:00"]` works for me to get a slice of the morning session, for example.

Comment: @agstudy sample.time = timeDate('2012-01-01 00:00:00')+15*60*(1:500)
data = 1:500
data.ts = xts(data,order.by=sample.time)
data.ts["T09:30/T11:00"]

Comment: @SlowLearner  You are right .. it simply works ... I was confused because I just used it on the time index and not on the xts object. Aplied to the object it simply works. data.ts["T09:30/T11:00"] works, but sample.time["T09:30/T11:00"] does not.

Comment: @SlowLearner ... I would accept, if your comment were an answer. ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `xts` object is called `x` then something like `y <- x["T09:30/T11:00"]` works for me to get a slice of the morning session, for example.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason to cut xts time of day using `x["T09:30/T11:00"]` is pretty slow, I use the method from [R: Efficiently subsetting dataframe based on time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554188/r-efficiently-subsetting-dataframe-based-on-time-of-day) and [data.table time subset vs xts time subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345951/data-table-time-subset-vs-xts-time-subset) to make a faster function with similar syntax:

```
cut_time_of_day <- function(x, t_str_begin, t_str_end){

    tstr_to_sec <- function(t_str){
        #"09:00:00" to sec of day
        as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste("1970-01-01", t_str), "UTC")) %% (24*60*60)
    }

    #POSIX ignores leap second
    #sec_of_day = as.numeric(index(x)) %% (24*60*60)                                #GMT only
    sec_of_day = {lt = as.POSIXlt(index(x)); lt$hour *60*60 + lt$min*60 + lt$sec}   #handle tzone
    sec_begin  = tstr_to_sec(t_str_begin)
    sec_end    = tstr_to_sec(t_str_end)

    return(x[ sec_of_day >= sec_begin & sec_of_day <= sec_end,])
}
```

Test:

```
n = 100000
dtime <- seq(ISOdate(2001,1,1), by = 60*60, length.out = n)
attributes(dtime)$tzone <- "CET"
x = xts((1:n), order.by = dtime)

y2 <- cut_time_of_day(x,"07:00:00", "09:00:00")
y1 <- x["T07:00:00/T09:00:00"]

identical(y1,y2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration of how much faster xts' time-of-day subsetting can be!  I've [created an issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/193) to work on improving it.

Comment: for those who are wondering ... the custom function above is still about 1000x faster than the internal xts function.

Comment: @ricardo: I get results that are hundreds of times faster, but not close to 1000x. Can you share your benchmark and `sessionInfo()` output? Feel free to email it to me.

Comment: In case anyone's still wondering the performance of both, I can confirm `xts` subsetting by time is about as fast, as of `0.13.0`; `microbenchmark` running 100 times of both (custom function vs xts subsetting) yields very close results, mean being 46.288 milisecs vs 48.521 milisecs, max being 57.142 milisecs vs 185 milisecs.