# Dynamic time-series prediction and rollapply

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to get a rolling prediction of a dynamic timeseries in R (and then work out squared errors of the forecast).  I based a lot of this code on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8488147), but I am very new to R so I am struggling quite a bit.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```r
require(zoo)
require(dynlm)

set.seed(12345)
#create variables
x<-rnorm(mean=3,sd=2,100)
y<-rep(NA,100)
y[1]<-x[1]
for(i in 2:100) y[i]=1+x[i-1]+0.5*y[i-1]+rnorm(1,0,0.5)
int<-1:100
dummydata<-data.frame(int=int,x=x,y=y)

zoodata<-as.zoo(dummydata)

prediction<-function(series)
  {
  mod<-dynlm(formula = y ~ L(y) + L(x), data = series) #get model
   nextOb<-nrow(series)+1
   #make forecast
   predicted<-coef(mod)[1]+coef(mod)[2]*zoodata$y[nextOb-1]+coef(mod)[3]*zoodata$x[nextOb-1]

   #strip timeseries information
   attributes(predicted)<-NULL

   return(predicted)
  }                

rolling<-rollapply(zoodata,width=40,FUN=prediction,by.column=FALSE)
```

This returns:

```
20          21      .....      80
10.18676  10.18676          10.18676
```

Which has two problems I was not expecting:

1. Runs from 20->80, not 40->100 as I would expect (as the width is 40)
2. The forecasts it gives out are constant: 10.18676

What am I doing wrong?  And is there an easier way to do the prediction than to write it all out?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your function is the `data` argument to `dynlm`. If you look in `?dynlm` you will see that the `data` argument must be a `data.frame` or a `zoo` object. Unfortunately, I just learned that `rollapply` splits your `zoo` objects into `array` objects. This means that `dynlm`, after noting that your `data` argument was not of the right form, searched for `x` and `y` in your *global* environment, which of course were defined at the top of your code. The solution is to convert `series` into a `zoo` object. There were a couple of other issues with your code, I post a corrected version here:

```
prediction<-function(series) {
   mod <- dynlm(formula = y ~ L(y) + L(x), data = as.zoo(series)) # get model
   # nextOb <- nrow(series)+1 # This will always be 21. I think you mean:
   nextOb <- max(series[,'int'])+1 # To get the first row that follows the window
   if (nextOb<=nrow(zoodata)) {   # You won't predict the last one
     # make forecast
     # predicted<-coef(mod)[1]+coef(mod)[2]*zoodata$y[nextOb-1]+coef(mod)[3]*zoodata$x[nextOb-1]
     # That would work, but there is a very nice function called predict
     predicted=predict(mod,newdata=data.frame(x=zoodata[nextOb,'x'],y=zoodata[nextOb,'y']))
     # I'm not sure why you used nextOb-1  
     attributes(predicted)<-NULL
     # I added the square error as well as the prediction.
     c(predicted=predicted,square.res=(predicted-zoodata[nextOb,'y'])^2)
   }
}    

rollapply(zoodata,width=20,FUN=prediction,by.column=F,align='right')
```

Your second question, about the numbering of your results, can be controlled by the `align` argument is `rollapply`. `left` would give you `1..60`, `center` (the default) would give you `20..80` and `right` gets you `40..100`.