# rolling computations in xts by month

Tags: r, subset, apply, xts, zoo

I am familiar with the `zoo` function `rollapply` which allows you to do rolling computations on `zoo` or `xts` objects and you can specify the rolling increment via the `by` parameter.  I am specifically interested in applying a function every month but using all of the past daily data in the computation.  For example say my data set looks like this:

```
dte, val
1/01/2001, 10
1/02/2001, 11
...
1/31/2001, 2
2/01/2001, 54
2/02/2001, 34
...
2/30/2001, 29
```

I would like to select the end of each month and `apply` a function that uses all the daily data.  This doesn't seem like it would work with `rollapply` since the `by` argument would be 30 sometimes, 29 other months, etc.  My current idea is:

```
f <- function(xts_obj) { coef(lm(a ~ b, data=as.data.frame(xts_obj)))[1] }
month_end <- endpoints(my_xts, on="months", k=1)
rslt <- apply(month_end, 1, function(idx) { my_xts[paste0("/",idx)] })
```

Surely there is a better way to do this that would be quicker no?
To clarify: I would like to use overlapping periods just the rolling should be done monthly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can get the dates of your endpoints, then for each endpoint (i.e. using `lapply` or `for`), call `rollapply` using data up to that point.

```
getSymbols("SPY", src='yahoo', from='2012-01-01', to='2012-08-01')
idx <- index(SPY)[endpoints(SPY, 'months')]
out <- lapply(idx, function(i) {
  as.xts(rollapplyr(as.zoo(SPY[paste0("/", i)]), 5, 
                    function(x) coef(lm(x[, 4] ~ x[, 1]))[2], by.column=FALSE))
})
sapply(out, NROW)
#[1]  16  36  58  78 100 121 142 143
```

I temporarily coerce to `zoo` for the `rollapplyr` to make sure the `rollapply.zoo` method is being used (as opposed to the unexported `rollapply.xts` method), then coerce back to `xts`

Comment: Is the zoo/xts conversion needed? I get the same result when I take them out.

Comment: @DarrenCook, It doesn't look like it's necessary, but I wanted to cover my bases.

Comment: @DarrenCook, If you want the results to be `xts`, then the `as.xts` is required assuming you're using `rollapply.zoo` which you will be unless you have PerformanceAnalytics loaded.  If you have PerformanceAnalytics loaded, then you'll be using `rollapply.xts`

Comment: @Gsee, I have been wondering how to solve a similar problem, less complex because I have to calculate function for each month using monthly data i.e. calculate trend using all the data availaible upto that time. How will I modify the above method given? What will be the width specified? Can I do this without rollapply?

Comment: @Anusha, this is the last question of yours I'm answering in the comments of another answer. The next question you ask you should post as a proper question.  Try this: `m <- to.monthly(SPY); m$trend <- sapply(seq_len(NROW(m)), function(i) coef(lm(as.numeric(Ad(m[1:i])) ~ c(1:i)))[2]); m`. and as an added bonus `chartSeries(OHLC(m), TA='addTA(m$trend)')`

Comment: @Gsee Thank you for the answer. I wanted to post a proper question but had this feeling that this question will be deemed highly related and so its better ask here itself if I am missing something basic.

Comment: @Gsee Also, this is the first question I have put in the comments of another question, ..surprised by your response.

Comment: @Anusha, sorry, I guess it was another Anusha. I hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: @Gsee Would you prefer that this question be posted separately?

Comment: @Anusha, if you understand the answer and you're satisfied with it, then no.  If you need further clarification, or if it doesn't answer your question, then yes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19129/discussion-between-anusha-and-gsee)

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to "Is the zoo/xts conversion needed?":
It isn't needed in this case, but rollapply won't work if you send it a dataframe, as I recently discovered from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583177/dynamic-time-series-prediction-and-rollapply)

Comment: `rollapply.xts` is now registered as an S3 method in the development version of **xts**.  However, it is not yet perfect; there is at least one case where it fails, but rollapply.zoo does not.

Answer (score 1):

You want `period.apply()`, or its convenience helper `apply.monthly()`, both in [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts).

Example:

```
R> foo <- xts(1:100, order.by=Sys.Date()+0:99)
R> apply.monthly(foo, sum)
           [,1]
2012-08-31  105
2012-09-30  885
2012-10-31 1860
2012-11-25 2200
R>
```

or equally

```
R> apply.monthly(foo, quantile)
           0%   25%  50%   75% 100%
2012-08-31  1  4.25  7.5 10.75   14
2012-09-30 15 22.25 29.5 36.75   44
2012-10-31 45 52.50 60.0 67.50   75
2012-11-25 76 82.00 88.0 94.00  100
R>
```

just to prove that functions returning more than one value can be used too.

Comment: but won't this simply do non overlapping periods? that is the stuff passed to sum are going to be the non-overlapping data in the months. i am trying to use all of the past data so that my periods are overlapping..

Comment: Oh, I see, that would indeed be different. But as you did not in fact provide a full example, I missed that.  Depending on what your aggregation function is, you could possibly still use `apply.monthly()` and aggregate afterwards. It all depends...

Comment: ok i just updated the question to make it more clear. sorry about that.