# R - rolling standard deviation on time

Tags: r, standards, standard-deviation

I have a quite a big dataset with the following columns : `Timestamp`, `Avg_Spend`.  The data is in milliseconds but not at regular interval e.g.  1 hour may 1000 obs, sometimes 2000 and so on.

I have to calculate rolling standard deviation over certain period such as say 5 hour. I tried using `runSD(caTools)`, which works very well on observation but am at loss as to how to get it to work for rolling time periods which may have varying observation. I can write custom loops, but those take long time. The solution has to be somehow vectorized.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How should the window move? From observation to observation? Or on fixed intervals? E.g. first windows 01:00 to 06:00, second from 01:05 to 06:05.

Comment: The window will move from observation to observation

Comment: Have a look at this other [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021171/rolling-computations-in-xts-by-month).

Comment: Paul, thanks for the link. In the other question they can use the all daily data from end point. It is a bit different and perhaps easier than my situation as I need to get that point which represents my moving window in minutes.  I finally managed to solve it, it takes a bit of time (15 minutes for 10 million rows) but gets the work done.  I just wrote  a custom loop where for each row, I get the first point in window.  Once I get the points, I use vector sd(abc[i:j]) to calculate sd. This seems faster than using formula for each row.